# Calculate user size to store in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, size

I'm creating a PostgreSQL DB where I'll store some users, so I need to know which is the exact size (MB) of each user.

This is my reasoning :

- Profile picture : JPEG 15 Mb 75% = up to 1,8 MB
- name + surname + work : 20 characters each so = 60 B
- date of birth : timestamp = 8 B
- bio : up to 500 characters = 500 B

For a total of (approximately) 2,5 MB.
So if I have 1 GB of available space on the DB I will store up to 400 users.

Is it right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL is a query _language_.)

Comment: The vast majority of the data you need to store is the image, with the bio coming in a distant second.  Your rough numbers are already accurate, though depending on the DB and column type, text might take more or less than this.

Comment: also index etc. I will suggest try to build the schema and insert one row, check how many space one row use and estimate base on that.

Comment: I wrote SQL because I still don't know which one I should use.
I would like to use postgreSQL because I used it once but I'm opened to new solutions. Someone suggested me Maria DB and Mongo DB.

Comment: I would not go down the mongo or document stored route as this works in a very different way to SQL, which catches people out, stick with SQL and investigate NoSql things like Mongo at a later date. I personally don't like NoSQL as it gets complex with demoralising data.

Comment: Who would close this as it was a valid question, jeez

Comment: I don't know why they closed my question

Comment: I wanted to use MongoDB to store only pictures, Maria or Postgres instead to store users and other.

Answer (score 1):

I would not store the image binary data in the database, this is not a good idea. Store it in azure blob storage and just store the url to it. At least not in the database, make the database as small and fast as possible or you will get issues later down the line. e.g. indexing with large columns will make queries slow down in time.

Comment: Mmmmh sounds a good idea to save space and make query smarter but how the process should work?
I'm on my application and I ask for user's info, the DB gives me what I need but then I still have to wait to get the picture from Azure server.
But this time is less than wait for big size query, is this the point right?

Comment: Yes with a url you leave it to the front end to just pull it down as a url image. The raw data will be smaller in your queries as you only get the minimum of what you need and make for a faster query. Azure blob services handle all the hard work as otherwise you would be sending down the image in your responses and presume it wont be as efficient as something that lots of people use, which has been tried and tested.

Comment: Is the Azure blob service expensive? Because I never used it...Can we have a private talk? Just a few minutes maybe on discord, google meet...Also text chat is good for me

Comment: You would have to do your research on how to upload and get a url from blob storage. You will need to setup an azure account. I will admit it does seem complex these days, we have done it at our place but I dont recall the full process. The simplest solution would be to store the file on the server if you are hosting it yourself. Like a folder in a hosted IIS  site and then return that url. But your really need the time and infrastructure to get something suitable.

Comment: Just googled and this one can get you started https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-and-writing-into-azure-blob-storage-using-net-core-console-app-and-c-sharp/

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to figure it out but I think I can do it